# regtest: ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: AcceptBlock FAILED: unexpected witness data found (code 16) on v0.14.3

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness, regtest

I have two bitcoind regtest processes; v0.16.3 and v0.14.3. I got "unexpected witness data found (code 16)" when v0.14.3 node try to received a block from the peer (v0.16.3)

How can I fix it? (I'm tring to reproduce CVE-2018-17144 error, the DoS issue, for learning. I think I reproduced the another issue, inflation bug. [reproduce CVE-2018-17144 (inflation bug) on regtest for learning](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84026/reproduce-cve-2018-17144-inflation-bug-on-regtest-for-learning))

This is what I did:

```
// start bitcoindA (v0.16.3)
$ /home/zono/bitcoinA/src/bitcoind -server -listen -port=17591 -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass -rpcport=16591 -datadir=$HOME/regtest/A/ -connect=localhost:17592 -regtest -pid=$HOME/regtest/A/.pid -daemon -debug

// start bitcoindB (v0.14.3)
$ /home/zono/bitcoinB/src/bitcoind -server -listen -port=17592 -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass -rpcport=16592 -datadir=$HOME/regtest/B/ -connect=localhost:17591 -regtest -pid=$HOME/regtest/B/.pid -daemon -debug

// generate a block on bitcoindA
$ ./bitcoin/src/bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass -rpcport=16591 -regtest generate 1

// check log on bitcoindB
$ tail -f /home/zono/regtest/B/regtest/debug.log

2019-01-27 03:36:27 Requesting block 086e6b0cdb854c4ffa08033af35a0a5866aebf1fe72195805401c4e7692861cb (1) peer=0
2019-01-27 03:36:27 sending getdata (37 bytes) peer=0
2019-01-27 03:36:27 received: block (262 bytes) peer=0
2019-01-27 03:36:27 received block 086e6b0cdb854c4ffa08033af35a0a5866aebf1fe72195805401c4e7692861cb peer=0
2019-01-27 03:36:27 ERROR: AcceptBlock: unexpected-witness, ContextualCheckBlock : unexpected witness data found (code 16)
2019-01-27 03:36:27 Misbehaving: 127.0.0.1:52872 peer=0 (0 -> 100) BAN THRESHOLD EXCEEDED
2019-01-27 03:36:27 ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: AcceptBlock FAILED
2019-01-27 03:36:27 sending reject (58 bytes) peer=0
2019-01-27 03:36:27 Warning: not banning local peer 127.0.0.1:52872!
```

---

Update 1

I found the segwit status of the v0.14.3 is "defined"

```
// bitcoindA (v0.16.3)
$ ./bitcoinA/src/bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass -rpcport=16591 getblockchaininfo
{
  "chain": "regtest",
  "blocks": 1,
  "bestblockhash": "4c5dab9fb090b4eec3d248a1531abf0e02f6f8d4f6331cefe574477c38a93c0d",
  "bip9_softforks": {
    "segwit": {
      "status": "active",
      "startTime": -1,
      "timeout": 9223372036854775807,
      "since": 0
    }
  }
}

// bitcoindB (v0.14.3)
$ ./bitcoinA/src/bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass -rpcport=16592 getblockchaininfo
{
  "chain": "regtest",
  "blocks": 0,
  "bestblockhash": "0f9188f13cb7b2c71f2a335e3a4fc328bf5beb436012afca590b1a11466e2206",
  "difficulty": 4.656542373906925e-10,
  "bip9_softforks": {
    "segwit": {
      "status": "defined",
      "startTime": 0,
      "timeout": 999999999999,
      "since": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I added "-prematurewitness" and "-walletprematurewitness" option but the result is same. (unexpected witness data found (code 16))

```
/home/zono/bitcoinB/src/bitcoind -server -listen -port=17592 -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass -rpcport=16592 -datadir=$HOME/regtest/B/ -connect=localhost:17591 -regtest -pid=$HOME/regtest/B/.pid -daemon -debug -prematurewitness -walletprematurewitness
```

Then, I tried to mine in bitcoindB (v0.14.3) but I got another error like following. (16: bad-witness-nonce-size)

```
2019-01-27 04:59:13 received: getdata (37 bytes) peer=0
2019-01-27 04:59:13 received getdata (1 invsz) peer=0
2019-01-27 04:59:13 received getdata for: witness-block 593a4919ae144569e83a6145e717b920fdd2a4267b427bdfd38c265d6bc5e1ea peer=0
2019-01-27 04:59:13 sending block (226 bytes) peer=0
2019-01-27 04:59:13 received: reject (62 bytes) peer=0
2019-01-27 04:59:13 Reject block code 16: bad-witness-nonce-size: hash 593a4919ae144569e83a6145e717b920fdd2a4267b427bdfd38c265d6bc5e1ea
2019-01-27 04:59:13 Unknown command "reject" from peer=0
```

seems I need to mine up to the certain block to active segwit.

> Did you activate segwit yet? Have you mined 288 blocks (IIRC that's the threshold for regtest) to activate segwit?

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1800935.0

---

Update 2

Segwit activated after generating 432 blocks based on this page. https://gist.github.com/t4sk/0bc6b35a26998b9007d68f376a852636

However, bitcoindA (v0.16.3) rejected the block due to "16: bad-witness-nonce-size"

```
// generate 432 blocks on bitcoindB (v0.14.3)
$ ./bitcoinB/src/bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass -rpcport=16591 -regtest generate 432

// check segwit status on bitcoindB (v0.14.3)
$ ./bitcoinB/src/bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass -rpcport=16592 getblockchaininfo
{
  "chain": "regtest",
  "blocks": 432,
  "headers": 432,
  "bestblockhash": "04488f65623bf43557e7874e5d576addf5b4f43bcd44821ba90876274de74347",
  "bip9_softforks": {
    "segwit": {
      "status": "active",
      "startTime": 0,
      "timeout": 999999999999,
      "since": 432
    }
  }
}

// check sync status on bitcoindA (v0.16.3)
$ ./bitcoinA/src/bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass -rpcport=16591 getblockchaininfo
{
  "chain": "regtest",
  "blocks": 0,
  "headers": 432,
  "bestblockhash": "0f9188f13cb7b2c71f2a335e3a4fc328bf5beb436012afca590b1a11466e2206",
}

// check log on bitcoindB (v0.14.3)
$ tail -f /home/zono/regtest/B/regtest/debug.log
2019-01-27 05:20:29 Reject block code 16: bad-witness-nonce-size: hash 0a11f9ae506ba184eef4a70e59e41599311c060c3466772bc632507cec973889
```

---

Update 3

I added "-vbparams=segwit:0:999999999999" param for bitcoind but still I get the error. "unexpected witness data found"

```
// bitcoindB (v0.14.3)
/home/zono/bitcoinB/src/bitcoind -server -listen -port=17592 -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=bitcoinrpcpass -rpcport=16592 -datadir=$HOME/regtest/B/ -connect=localhost:17591 -regtest -pid=$HOME/regtest/B/.pid -daemon -debug -vbparams=segwit:0:999999999999

// The error message on bitcoindB (v0.14.3) after generating 1 block on bitcoindA (v0.16.3)
2019-01-28 08:37:29 ERROR: AcceptBlock: unexpected-witness, ContextualCheckBlock : unexpected witness data found (code 16)

// The result of getblockchaininfo on bitcoindB (v0.14.3). Still the status is "defined"
"bip9_softforks": {
  "segwit": {
    "status": "defined",
    "startTime": 0,
    "timeout": 999999999999,
    "since": 0
  }
```

Comment: I think the network parameters of regtest may have changed between versions.

Comment: @zono, could you try with adding `vbparams=segwit:0:999999999999` to the v0.14.3 node's `bitcoin.conf` file?

Comment: @arubi thank you. but still no luck. I added the result as "update 3".

Comment: @zono, yea I see now - one defined and one is already active at genesis.  It might work then if you also add `vbparams=segwit:0:99999999999` to the v0.16.3 node, so they both have the same setting.  I'm almost positive that I had this setup working before, but unfortunately I didn't keep the `.conf` files

Comment: @arubi Thank you! It worked. When you have time, can you post your comment as an answer so that I can show this question was solved. (simple answer is ok, e.g "add vbparams=segwit:0:99999999999 in .conf on both the nodes")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the two nodes do not agree on segwit's activation scheme on regtest, the solution is to set a common `version bits` parameter to both of them.
For example, adding `vbparams=segwit:0:99999999999` in the two nodes' `.conf` files will work.